# Left shift a specific no. of 1s specific no. of times

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitmask

I would like to left shift a specific no. of ones a specific no. of times. I am trying something like this

```
//Left shift 3 1's by 5. 
int a = 0; 
a = 0b(111 << 5) ;  //Error : unable to find numeric literal
                    // operator 'operator""b'        
std::cout << a; //Should be 224
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix the above ? Ideally I would like something like this

```
int a = 0;
int noOfOnes = 3;
a = 0b(noOfOnes << 5);
```

I am not sure how I would accomplish the above in C++ ?

Comment: Is either known before?

Comment: @Deduplicator I know how many 1's are needed at runtime

Comment: Why is there a random `0b`, not part of an integer literal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's as simple as `((1u << a) - 1u) << b`, where `a` is the number of `1`s, and `b` is the offset.

---

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

unsigned foo(unsigned size, unsigned offset)
{
    return ((1u << size) - 1u) << offset;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned x = foo(5, 3);
    std::cout << std::bitset<16>(x); // 0000000011111000
}
```

<kbd>[Try it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/853a61955f9c103d)</kbd>

---

This approach breaks if `a (or b) >= sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT` (thanks @Deduplicator)

If it's still a problem after switching to a largest available integral type, you can add some safety checks:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>

unsigned foo(unsigned size, unsigned offset)
{
    unsigned x = 0; 
    if (offset >= sizeof x * CHAR_BIT)
        return 0;
    if (size < sizeof x * CHAR_BIT)
        x = 1u << size;
    return (x - 1u) << offset;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned x = foo(32, 3);
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(x);
}
```